# Concept Shader to achieve such Toon/Graphical Novel look style

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders, unity-shader-graph, unity-urp

[image: Person]

Hi to all,

I have no clue how to achieve this kind of style (DallE Ai picture) by having a shader and custom textures applied to a 3D object.

I see an outline (maybe sobel on normals and depth), and a lot of noise which reminds me of some Watercolor shaders. But other than that I have no idea.

I would be grateful for some help/ideas what components a shader should have to make this (I am using Unity HDRP for now)

Cheers!

Comment: The closest you will get is with a cell shader, manual generation or photo reduction.